# How to dismiss an info-window in android Google map API v2

Tags: android, infowindow

I am trying to dismiss an info-window in an android program but i can't do this. Here i am using a click listener like

```
mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener( new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){                           @Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
alert.showpickAlertDialog2(PlacesMapActivity.this, slat, slon, REFERENCE);              }
  }
 );
```

but i don't know the right code to dismiss an infowindow. Somebody please help to fix this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try :

```
marker.hideInfoWindow();
```

in your case arg0.hideInfoWindow()

Answer (score 3):

```
mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener( new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){                           @Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
arg0.hideInfoWindow();
alert.showpickAlertDialog2(PlacesMapActivity.this, slat, slon, REFERENCE);              }
  }
 );
```